# Creating New Column with Maximum Value

Tags: r, max

I've spent a good deal of time looking into this subject, but have not been able to find much. I would like a new column of data titled "Max Region", that gives the name of the column for which the maximum value occurs in each row.

```
df <- data.frame(Head=c(9, 6, 2, NA), Thorax=c(9, 2, NA, NA), Abdomen=c(NA, NA, 5, 5), Neck=c(4, 3, 5, 2))

#  Head Thorax Abdomen Neck
#    9      9      NA    4
#    6      2      NA    3
#    2     NA       5    5
#   NA     NA       5    2
```

So far, I've used:

```
df$MaxRegion <- names(df)[apply(df, 1, which.max)]
```

However, in the case of a tie, I would really like both columns to result (ie HeadThorax or AbdomenNeck), or just result with "NA". Is this possible with which.max? I've also looked into max.col, but it also doesn't seem to have this function. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using the OP's code, if we need to get all the tied `max` element column names, use `%in%`(returns FALSE where there are NA) or `==` on the `max`, and `paste` the corresponding `names`

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x %in% max(x, na.rm = TRUE)]))
#[1] "Head, Thorax"  "Head"          "Abdomen, Neck" "Abdomen"
```

NOTE: `which.max` returns only the first index of the `max` value

Comment: Great, thank you so much. How do I get this into a new column? I tried: df$MaxRegion <- names(df)[apply(df, 1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x %in% max(x, na.rm = TRUE)]))], but the column is only resulting in NA.

Comment: @krazyglue5 you just need `df$MaxRegion <- apply(df, 1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x %in% max(x, na.rm = TRUE)]))`. We are already subsetting the `names` inside the `apply`

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option

```
df$MaxRegion <- mapply(
  subset,
  list(names(df)),
  asplit(df == do.call(pmax, c(df, na.rm = TRUE)), 1)
)
```

gives

```
> df
  Head Thorax Abdomen Neck     MaxRegion
1    9      9      NA    4  Head, Thorax
2    6      2      NA    3          Head
3    2     NA       5    5 Abdomen, Neck
4   NA     NA       5    2       Abdomen
```